# How java serverSocket and client socket interacts within the same pc?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

In accordance to example in this link:
http://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming

As i understand port no :`6666` is an imaginary or raw port used to illustrate socket programming. I want to know how the PC knows that it has server with port 6666 after running both `myClient.java` and `myServer.java`.

Also I want to know while doing Real socket programming the `myServer.java` needs to be placed in real server location if not then where ? just want to understand where to initialize a `serverSocket` class object! In server side or in client side ?

Also how Operating system or PC(in general ) search for available ports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked document is broken, nevertheless, let me explain a bit how the network sockets work.

A computer has multiple network interfaces. If you're running window you can check them by running `ipconfig /all`, on linux/osx with `ifconfig`. You'll see that you have a loopback interface with IP address 127.0.0.1. Also, by convenience it was decided to add a "name" to this loopback interface, and it'd be `localhost`. You can verify this in `/etc/hosts` file where a mapping between 127.0.0.1 and localhost exists.

Saying that, a computer can find a route to localhost on himself using the system kernel. This loopback interface is virtual, implemented in the operating system so no packets will go through your Ethernet interface or wifi card.

TCP and UDP are protocols used on top of IP to send data. TCP establishes a connection via the [3-way handshake](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and packet reception is acknowledged by the server. UDP is non-connection oriented, so a client will send packets to the ports and no acknowledges are sent. That's just a huge summary.

When you want to listen on a port, your application needs to actually tell it to the operating system and when the networking component of the OS receives some packets with the TCP.dst value equal to 6666 (in your case) it will send the payload to your application. The OS is responsible for acknowledging the packets and all the underlaying communication which is transparent from you.

As you might guess, the operating system can only bind the same port port to a single application. That's why if you start twice a web server, the second execution will fail.

You can check which ports are listening with `netstat -l` on a linux machine.